# UCASE not working with AES_DECRYPT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I am trying to fetch upper case data from column which has AES Encrypted data. Column data type is varbinary

```
SELECT UCASE(AES_DECRYPT(first_name,'TEST')) from mytable

Sample Data
first_name
James
PHIL
PRESTON

EXPECTED
first_name
JAMES
PHIL
PRESTON
```

Result, its returning data in original case instead of returning upper case data.
Any suggestion what is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Just found solution!, updating here it might help someone else!, Seems after converting DECRYPTED result to CHAR it worked!

```
SELECT UCASE(CAST(AES_DECRYPT(first_name,'TEST') AS CHAR)) from my table.
```